# How to Field Separate and append text using awk

Tags: awk

Experts,

I have the following text in an xml files ( there will 20,000 rows in file).

```
<record record_no = "1" error_code="101">&quot;21006041&quot;;&quot;28006041&quot;;&quot;34006211&quot;;&quot;43&quot;;&quot;101210-0001&quot;
```

Here is how I need the result for each row to be and append to new file.

```
 "21006041";"28006041";"34006211";"43";"101210-0001";101
```

Here is what I need to do to get the above result.

- I replaced `&quot;` with "
- remove `<record record_no = "1" error_code="`
- Get the text 101 ( it can have any value in this position)
- append to the last.

Here is what I have been trying.

```
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
        /<record/ {
            gsub(/&quot;/,"\"")
            gsub(/&apos;/,"")
                gsub(/.*="|">.*/,"",$1)
$(NF+1)=$1;
$1="";
print $0;
}
```

Comment: Use a command line XML parser like XMLStarlet and do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

`awk -F'">' -v OFS=';' '{gsub(/<record record_no = \"[0-9]+\" error_code="/,""); gsub(/&quot;/,"\""); print $2,$1}'`

The strategy is to:

1. split the string at closing chars of the xml element `">`
2. remove the first bit of the xml element including the attribute names leaving only the error code.
3. replace all `&quot;` xml entities with `"`.
4. print the two FS sections in reverse order.

Test it out with the following data generation script.  The script will generate 500x20000 line files with records of random length, some with dashes in the values.

```
#!/bin/bash
recCount=0
for h in {1..500};
do
    for i in {1..20000};
    do
        ((recCount++))
        error=$(( RANDOM % 998 + 1 ))
        record="<record record_no = "'"'"${recCount}"'"'" error_code="'"'"${error}"'"'">"
        upperBound=$(( RANDOM % 4 + 5 ))
        for (( k=0; k<${upperBound}; k++ ));
        do
            randomVal=$(( RANDOM % 99999999 + 1))
            record+="&quot;${randomVal}"
            if [[ $((RANDOM % 4)) == 0 ]];
            then
                randomVal=$(( RANDOM % 99999999 + 1))
                record+="-${randomVal}"
            fi    
            record+="&quot;"
            if [[ $k != $(( ${upperBound} - 1 )) ]];
            then
                record+=";"
            fi    
        done;
        echo "${record}" >> "file-${h}.txt"
    done;
done;
```

On my laptop I get the following performance.

```
$ time cat file-*.txt | awk -F'">' -v OFS=';' '{gsub(/<record record_no = \"[0-9]+\" error_code="/,""); gsub(/&quot;/,"\""); print $2,$1}' > result

real    0m18.985s
user    0m17.673s
sys 0m2.697s
```

As an added bonus, here is the "equivalent" command in sed:
`sed -e 's|\(&quot;\)|"|g' -e 's|^.*error_code="\([^>]\+\)">\(.\+\).*$|\2;\1|g'`

Much slower although the strategy is the same.  Two expressions are used.  First replace all `&quot;` xml entities with `"`. Lastly group all characters (.+) after `>`.  Display the remembered patterns in reverse order `\2;\1`

Timing statistics:

```
$ time cat file-* | sed -e 's|\(&quot;\)|"|g' -e 's|^.*error_code="\([^>]\+\)">\(.\+\).*$|\2;\1|g' > result.sed

real    5m59.576s
user    5m56.136s
sys 0m9.850s
```

Comment: Donavan,This works great , however if I have to process 500 files and each file containing 20K records. Does this solution to loop through works faster ?

Comment: Does it have to be `awk`? What about `sed`.
This command runs under a second for 20K records:
`sed -e 's/\(&quot;\)/"/g' -e 's|^.*error_code= \([^>]\+\)>\(.\+\).*$|\2;\1|g'`

Comment: I completely revised my answer to better suit the context of the problem 500 files * 20000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Is this too thick:

```
$ awk -F"&quot;+" -v OFS='";"' -v dq='"' '{gsub(/^.*="|">$/,"",$1);print dq""$2,$4,$6,$8,$10dq";"$1}' test.in
"21006041";"28006041";"34006211";"43";"101210-0001";101
```

Comment: Thanks looking into it, however NF are not constant.